# How do I approach linear algebra proving problems in general?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have massive problems with questions like these:

Let $\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$
(with
$r < n$), and let $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$  be a vector such that $w \in \mathrm{span}\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$.
Prove that $\{v_1, . . . , v_r, w\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$
Define the set $U + V = \{u + v|u ∈ U, v ∈ V \}$. Prove that $U + V$
is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm not looking for the answers to these 2 questions but instead I want to know how do I learn to approach these problems. These proving problems are my absolute Achilles' heel. I can't get the solution at all. What can I do to learn to solve these problems? Any online resources you guys can recommend? I usually learn how to do real questions by following examples but I get nothing from watching people talk about these theories and principles behind how it's done...

Comment: This may be harsh but it is the truth; "you learn mathematics by doing mathematics." In a case like this, you just have to apply the definition.

Comment: It can help to have someone guide you through it and give you hints. You could go to office hours and ask for hints, not full solutions, and see if they will help guide you through it. It can also help to write down what you are given explicitly, and write down what you want to show explicitly. For the first theorem, what are you given? Can you write it out explicitly? What do you want to show?

Comment: The first problem is wrong. You should try to prove that set as a  *linearly Depedent set*.

Comment: For the first theorem, shouldn't the conclusion be "linearly dependent"? Alternatively, shouldn't we assume that $w$ is not in the span of the other vectors?

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment, go to office hours and tell them explicitly what you have tried. Then ask for a hint. Once you have seen the full solution, ask yourself how you could have figured that out without hints.

Comment: The first question is wrong? I just copied the entire question from my tutorial...

Comment: For the first question, I think you mean $w \notin \ldots$ right?

Comment: yes, thanks. That didnt copy over correctly

Answer (score 2):

Linear Algebra questions are usually based on the definition of linear independence. Once you get the hang of it, the problems make much more sense.

For a good on-line resource, you could try [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no sure work formula to  successfully prove something and there could be multiple ways to solve the same thing . The advices in the comments are very useful.

Reading mathematics does help if you can see the thought process.

Mathematical proofs is really like solving real life problem.
I usually ask myself questions to guide myself to solve problems:

- what is my goal?
- what tools do I have?
- how do i use my tools to reach my goal?
- if I get stucked, can I use tricks like contradiction or contrapositive to prove it. Do I have other lemmas or theorems that can help me achieve my goal.
- Sometimes, you really get stucked, ask for help/ hint from tutor/ friends. Take a walk around and come back to the question later. Try to solve special cases or look at similar questions.

For example, in the first question:

Let $\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$
(with
$r < n$), and let $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$  be a vector such that $w \notin \mathrm{span}\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$.
Prove that $\{v_1, . . . , v_r, w\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Goal: prove that $\{v_1, . . . , v_r, w\}$ is a linearly independent set.

hmmm... what does linearly independent set mean?  Let me check the definition and rewrite it.

New goal: If $\sum_{i=1}^r c_iv_i+c_{r+1}w = 0$, show that $c_i=0, \forall i=1, \ldots, r+1.$

Now let's see what do we know about $v_i$ and $w$.

Tool $1$: Let $\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$
(with
$r < n$). Meaning, whenever I form a linear combination of $v_i$ and equate it to $0$, the coefficients must be $0$.

Tool $2$: $w \notin \mathrm{span}\{v_1, . . . , v_r\}$, that is $w$ cannot be written as linear combination of $v_i$.

The second tool motivates me to try to isolate $w$.Hence, it is natural to consider whether :

- case 1: $c_{r+1}=0$: If $\sum_{i=1}^r c_iv_i+c_{r+1}w = 0$ and $c_{r+1}=0$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^r c_iv_i = 0$ and we can check our tool list and see that we can use tool $1$ to conclude that $c_i=0, \forall i=1,\ldots, r$.
- case 2: $c_{r+1}\neq0$: We better get a contradiction for this case, as we really want $c_{r+1}$ to be zero. Suppose it is not, $w =-\frac{1}{c_{r+1}}\sum_{i=1}^r c_iv_i$, check our tool list and we can see that tool $2$ says that we can't have this case.

Comment: thanks. It makes sense. I guess my problem would be my lack of knowledge of what those mathematical terms mean(definition). So, I think its my lack of understanding of the basic principles. I can solve physics and calculus problems just fine. Just suck at linear algebra badly...

Comment: @sdkessler One benefit of writing out what you want to show explicitly is that you are forced to realize it if you do not understand the meaning of certain terms; in that case simply look up the definitions of those terms (and attempt to understand the definitions clearly).  You will be amazed at how much your theorem proving ability improves with very persistent practice.